# Where is the share button in firefox 23?

Tags: firefox

I just upgraded Firefox to the latest version to date (23) and while I can see the new logo, I can't find the share button. I tried with all add-ons disabled, but nothing changed. I tried to custom my toolbars, but there was no appropriate button in the proposed stack.

Comment: Well, firefox is a browser, not a file manager to share something from it. I don't remember seeing ever such a button integrated in a browser. Anyway, what do you want to share from firefox and where?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu Firefox 23 comes with this button, see https://blog.mozilla.org/blog/2013/08/06/firefox-makes-it-easy-to-share-your-favorite-content-with-friends-family/

Comment: @Chris Well, the OP didn't mention nothing about a *share button for Facebook*. Anyway, I see this thing disgusting if I will see that button by default in my Firefox...

Comment: It was said in the press release that a new "Social API" was introduced, which enables such Add-Ons to integrate deeper into the Browser (show new messages count for instance).. There was not said they had added a facebook button, but some blogs wrote it in a way, that you could get the impression that firefox implemented a facebook button only, instead of an API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first need to visit [this page](https://www.facebook.com/about/messenger-for-firefox) which tells you how to install "Messenger for Firefox". Only after that will you see the "social" button. And there's a video here: https://blog.mozilla.org/blog/2012/12/03/firefox-gets-social-w-facebook/

Answer (score 0):

vasa1 is right. You will have to enable Messenger for Firefox in order to see the built-in share button. Firefox should have informed this by means of a popup, once the browser updated to 23.0

Here's a helpful tutorial with screenshots which will show you how to enable the built-on share

[Enable Built-In Share in Firefox 23](http://www.fixnowsupport.com/3/post/2013/08/how-to-enable-built-in-share-button-in-firefox-23.html)